# Selenium submit not working even though keyboard submit works

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to learn web crawling and figured LinkedIn would be a fun website to test.  I am experimenting with logging in, and searching for the term "example" and then hitting return (as there is no clickable search button).  The issue I am experiencing is that, after I log in and enter the text bar, I can physically hit "enter" on my keyboard after typing and the search bar will submit the text and take me to the next screen.  But for some reason, when I use the "submit" function within selenium, I get an error, even though it is successfully used during the login procedure.  Code as follows:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")
browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com')

username = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#session_key')
username.send_keys('email')
sleep(2)

password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#session_password')
password.send_keys('password')
sleep(2)

password.submit()
sleep(2)

search = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.search-global-typeahead__input')
search.send_keys('example')
sleep(2)

search.submit()
```

I end up getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#123>", line 1, in <module>
search.submit()
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 85, in submit
form = self.find_element(By.XPATH, "./ancestor-or-self::form")
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 658, in find_element
return self._execute(Command.FIND_CHILD_ELEMENT,
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
 return self._parent.execute(command, params)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: ./ancestor-or-self::form
```

**Update**

The following code worked thanks to Abrar's answer.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.search-global-typeahead__input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Deleted the following line.

```
search.submit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Step 2. driver.find_element_by_name("").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Note: you have to write Keys.ENTER
```

This is what you can try

Comment: Worked great with a slight tweak, updated solution in my question.  Thanks!

Comment: The answer had `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys` this as the first line. :)

Comment: omg I only saw from Step 2 on.  Need more coffee!  Thanks again!